# requesting relationship status from the instagram API?

Tags: json, api, instagram

I'm trying to work with the instagram api, and I'm  not seeming to understand one of their request call from the relationship endpoint, so here goes,

```
GET /users/{user-id}/relationship
```

"Get information about the current user's relationship (follow/following/etc) to another user."

this information comes from this page http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/

this is what it returns:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "data": {
        "outgoing_status": "none", 
        "incoming_status": "requested_by"
    }
}
```

what i don't understand is if the current user is lets say id 3
and the target user 61

```
and id 3 does follow id 61

and id 61 deosnt follow 3
```

what would the instagram api return!! thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the very top of the documentation page you linked to:

> - `outgoing_status`: Your relationship to the user. Can be "`follows`", "`requested`", "`none`".
> - `incoming_status`: A user's relationship to you. Can be "`followed_by`", "`requested_by`", "`blocked_by_you`", "`none`".

So for your scenario it would be:

```
"data": {
  "outgoing_status": "follows", 
  "incoming_status": "none"
}
```